# How can I access/replace an iframe in a Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I am reading [the documentation on Chrome Apps and CSP.](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#webview) However the behaviour I'm seeing in the browser doesn't match the documentation, and the documentation itself seems contradictory - specifically:

> iframes that point to remote URLs, which are disabled inside Chrome Apps.

vs, on the exact same page:

> Sandboxed pages can use iframes

Which seemingly includes remote iframes allowed by the `permissions` in manifest.

My use case is fairly simple: I want to embed the Spotify player inside my Chrome app, which is normally done with

`<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`

My `manifest.json`

```
"app": {
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  }
},
"permissions": [
  "https://embed.spotify.com/*"
],
"sandbox": {
  "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
},
```

And my sandbox.html (which is in its own iframe on the background page):

```
<body>
  <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs" width="300"  height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

However I still get:

> Refused to frame '[https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs](https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3atrack:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs)' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".
>    sandboxed.html:2

Even though this matches the **Embedding a sandboxed page in an app page** example. Maybe I should use a webview instead? The docs don't make it clear.

**Can I access an external site in an iframe or not?** If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phrase:

> iframes that point to remote URLs, which are disabled inside Chrome Apps.

Is not true. iframes that point to remote URLs are disabled **by default**, but there are two mechanisms to load iframes that point to remote URLs:

- If you have **content that's loaded from the web (eg, it needs to be up to date) but which is not interacted with from the rest of the app, use a webview**. webview can access iframes, but they can't communicate with the rest of the app at all. On the other hand, they're nice and simple to set up.
- If you have **content that's loaded from the web and interacted with from the rest of your app, use sandboxing**:

  1. Make a normal page (included in your Chrome app) which, being a regular Chrome app page, has access to chrome.* APIs, which loads a sandboxed page (2) in an iframe
  2. Make a sandboxed page (included in your extension) with an iframe pointing to the third party site, a third party script, etc.
  3. The third party site lives in the iframe from (2)

Then use the [HTML5 postMessage() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send messages from 1 to 2. Eg, page 1 can use a chrome.* API to do a thing, then post a message to the sandbox page. The sandboxed page then receives that message and can take some action.

In my case:

- (2) loads the soundcloud API (which uses an iframe, eg (3))
- (1) uses postmessage() to tell (2) to play a track, which the soundcloud API does in the iframe (3).